# Show content based on date (date before, date after, date between)

Tags: php, date

This is setup to show a button between 2 dates set. And to show a "Sign up starts at xxx" before the set start up date, and "Sign up closed the xxxx" after the set end date...

Somehow nothing shows for the "active periode" / the dates in betweeen...

```
$DateToday = date('Ymd');
$DateStart = get_field('pamelding_fra');
$DateEnd = get_field('pamelding_slutt');
$DateStartOut = new DateTime($DateStart);
$DateEndOut = new DateTime($DateEnd);

 if ($DateStart >= $DateToday){

     $ClassStatus = "<div class=\"OpenClassButton\"><span   class=\"ClassFullWarning\">Påmeldingen åpner " . $DateStartOut->format('j M Y') . "</span></div>";
     $ClassButton = $ClassStatus;

 }elseif ($DateEnd <= $DateToday){

     $ClassStatus = "<div class=\"OpenClassButton\"><span class=\"ClassFullWarning\">Påmeldingen stengte " . $DateEndOut->format('j M Y') . "</span></div>";
     $ClassButton = $ClassStatus;

 }elseif ($DateStart <= $DateToday && $DateEnd >= $DateToday){

    //Do some stuff - show button, this is the active time.    
 }
```

Might not be best-practice and I might make stuff difficult for me, suggestions appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't compare dates using date strings. If they are in different formats (like `Ymd`, `mdY` etc) you will get unwanted results. Use unix timestamps instead.

```
$today = time(); // Get today's timestamp

if ($today < strtotime($DateStart)) {
    // Do stuff before
} elseif ($today > strtotime($DateEnd)) {
    // Do stuff after
} else {
    // Active. No need for any conditions here,
    // since we only have three states.
}
```

Comment: The date start and date end is Jquery datestamps (20160211) YYDDMM
How will this affect?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. `strtotime()` converts those dates to timestamps. I just tested the above code with dates in that format so...